# Does not show the value of the calculations after the calculation

Tags: c++

Asked homework. I can not understand where the error ... what can you say about my code?

It is necessary to perform the calculation in the method main(). To calculate the smallest remainder of the division, I use the Euclidean algorithm (iterative).

Further further operations with fractions are performed. As I understand it, the error occurs when reducing fractions.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Fraction {

    private:
        int a; // числитель
        int b; // знаменатель
        //алгоритм Евклида (итерационный)
        int nod(int x, int y) {
            while (x != y) {
                if (x > y) {
                    long tmp = x;
                    x = y;
                    y = tmp;
                }
                y = y - x;
            }
            return x;
        }

    public:
        void Show() {
            cout << this->a << "/" << this->b;
        }
        // конструктор по умолчанию (числитель = 0, знаменатель = 1)
        Fraction() {
            this->a = 0; this->b = 1;
        }
        // конструктор с заданным числителем x и знаменателем y
        Fraction(int x, int y) {
            if (y != 0) {
                this->a = x; this->b = y;
            }
            else cout << "Error" << endl;
        }
        // Методы для свойства - числитель
        void setNumerator(int x) {
            this->a = x;
        }
        int getNumerator() {
            return this->a;
        }
        //Методы для свойства числитель
        void setDeNumerator(int x) {
            if (x == 0) printf("Delenie ne nol!\n");
            else this->b = x;
        }
        int getDeNumerator() {
            return this->a;
        }
        void Irreducible() {
            int node = nod(this->a, this->b); // НОд числителя и знаменателя
            this->a / node;
            this->b / node;
        }
};

Fraction operator+(Fraction & x, Fraction & y) {
    Fraction c;
    c.setNumerator(x.getNumerator() * y.getDeNumerator() + x.getDeNumerator() * y.getNumerator());
    c.setDeNumerator(x.getDeNumerator() * y.getDeNumerator());
    c.Irreducible();
    return c;
}

Fraction operator-(Fraction & x, Fraction & y) {
    Fraction c;
    c.setNumerator(x.getNumerator() * y.getDeNumerator() - x.getDeNumerator() * y.getNumerator());
    c.setDeNumerator(x.getDeNumerator() * y.getDeNumerator());
    c.Irreducible();
    return c;
}

Fraction operator*(Fraction & x, Fraction & y) {
    Fraction c;
    c.setNumerator(x.getNumerator() * y.getNumerator());
    c.setDeNumerator(x.getDeNumerator() * y.getDeNumerator());
    c.Irreducible();
    return c;
}

Fraction operator/(Fraction & x, Fraction & y) {
    Fraction c;
    c.setNumerator(x.getNumerator() * y.getDeNumerator());
    c.setDeNumerator(x.getDeNumerator() * y.getNumerator());
    c.Irreducible();
    return c;
}

int main() {
    int ch, zn;
    cout << "chis1="; cin >> ch;
    cout << "znam1="; cin >> zn;
    Fraction f1(ch, zn);
    cout << "chis2="; cin >> ch;
    cout << "znam2="; cin >> zn;
    Fraction f2(ch, zn);
    Fraction sum = f1 + f2;
    f1.Show(); cout << "+"; f2.Show(); cout << " ="; sum.Show(); cout << endl;
    Fraction raz = f1 - f2;
    f1.Show(); cout << "-"; f2.Show(); cout << " ="; raz.Show(); cout << endl;
    Fraction pro = f1 * f2;
    f1.Show(); cout << "*"; f2.Show(); cout << " ="; pro.Show(); cout << endl;
    Fraction div = f1 / f2;
    f1.Show(); cout << "/"; f2.Show(); cout << " ="; div.Show(); cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check the compiler warnings. It should be warning you that `this->a / node;` and `this->b / node;` have no effect. The result of the operation isn't assigned anywhere.

Comment: Your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) would like to discuss `int getDeNumerator() {
            return this->a;
        }` with you

Comment: With pencil on paper, execute `nod` with `x` = 0 and `y` = 1. You could be at it for a long while .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Need replace `this->a / node` to `this->a /= node`